# How to integrate menu/footer/menu in PHP MVC

Tags: php, html

i know that this question already has been asked. But i still dont understand it.

Right now im trying to understand how to make use of the MVC Modell. 
But i dont get how to integrate everything and right now I am hesitating to use a framework before i really get it.

What I try to achieve:

**I want to have a header, a footer and a menu which remain the same all the time.** 
Like this:

HEADER
MENU
{CONTENT}
FOOTER

So my thinking is:

My Controller gets some Information, lets say its a User-ID.

Controller calls a method from the Model:
Get all DATA from USER with ID: 1

Then the controller passes the DATA into a view, lets say a list.

---

**So where to go from here?
Should the controller pass this view into another view?**

Like:

```
$site = new View(); <br>
$site->wholeSite($content);
```

and then site is something like:

HEADER
MENU
`{$content}`
FOOTER

Please excuse my simple approach, im just trying to get the basic idea behind it and i already read the first 20 pages of googling it. 
Just cant get my head around it.....
It would be really nice if you would explain it for an Beginner :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

you can call multiple views from the control like:

```
$this->load->view('header',$data);
$this->load->view('menu',$data);
$this->load->view('content',$data);
$this->load->view('footer',$data);
```

If you have a nested div then you can use regular include function like from a particular view file.

```
include('footer.php');
```

According to the path of the view file. The data also gets transferred from parent view to the included file.

Answer (score 0):

Generally MVC apps have a universal layout view which contains the header, footer and menus. Sometimes data required for that is handled outside the controller, in say your init script or bootstrap.

An MVC purist might pass all data the layout requires from the controller, but that can be repetitive, although setting the data in an abstract controller construct might alleviate that.

On the question of views and sub-views there are generally two solutions:

A.) You have one principle view which all required data is passed to. In that view sub-views (partials) are called, and data is passed down into them.

B.) You instantiate all your views in the controller, passing all the data they need directly into the view, you would then pass views as parameters into other views.

Both methods have their pros and cons. I find the first option leads to less Fat Controllers, so I usually go with that.

I'd recommend you learn an existing MVC framework ( CodeIgniter, now defunct is basic enough to make it a good entry point), as that will show you how things are done.